# Table Optimization - Multiple Fields VS Multiple Tables

Tags: mysql

I'm questioning my MySQL database best practices right now and trying to figure this out. I have a form that users will fill out YES/NO and in case of YES, there's an extra field to explain themselves. There's about 36 fields, and the table would be 1>1. Say 15 fields apply to (A) user, 8 apply to (B) user, 8 to (C) user and 5 apply to (D) user. Would it be better to have separate tables with 15, 8, 8 and 5 fields or one big 36 field table with some empty fields? I'm looking for performance and normalization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my option, the answer depends on whether the list will *ever* change.  If not, one wide table will be "cleaner" (easier to query, etc).  If you need to change the list, trying to rebuild a large existing table in MySQL is a nightmare, so you're better off with an attribute table.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Alright I was thinking that maybe one large table wouldnt be very efficient and require more processing from the server that's why I was considering calling different tables with conditions. Thanks!

Comment: There's certainly a difference between 30 char(200) and 30 ints - disk IO, etc.

Answer (score 0):

To be properly normalized, create a separate junction table to link the users who answer "yes" with their explanations. You do not want to find yourself in a situation where you have to alter the Users table just because a 37<sup>th</sup> explanation is added to the system.